# Using refs in react

Tags: reactjs

The React documentation contains the following warning:

> Never access refs inside of any component's render method - or while any component's render method is even running anywhere in the call stack.

Why? My problem is, I'm writing a component which lays out its children in ways that depend on the children sizes. That is, I need to measure the DOM nodes so I need to access each child, which I was planning to do via refs, in render. What's wrong with that? Of course, I need to allow for the fact that some children may not yet exist in refs (in the first render, no child exists).

Incidentally, my render seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer:* I'm not a React core developer, but I use it quite extensively on a large project.

TL;DR: The safest place is to use lifecycle methods, in the `.render()` method the component is still only a declarative description of what is to be done.

Beacuse what you construct in your `.render()` method isn't the component that is going to be rendered, it's a *description* of what you want React to construct for you. That construction happens later (that's when all the optimisations comes in). At the same time, the object you returned to `React.createClass` will get substituted for a new object. Visualize it like you are sending a letter to React (the object sent to `.createClass()`) and React responds with a package (the component). If you need to do something with the sub-components that will be created go look in the [lifecycle methods](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html). `.refs` should be populated by the time of `.componentDidMount()`.

Comment: Jacob, I'm aware of that. BTW, the container refs will not be populated when componentWillMount. componentWillMount is called before render, so no children have been created yet. The very first container render won't see anything in refs. Later, the children will be created and refs populated. In the next render, I want to use them. What's the problem?

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify something. All the children have unique keys and the ref in each child is the key. I expect that once refs[key] is set it will never change as long as the child exists. Am I wrong in my expectations?

Comment: I would still use lifecycle methods, f.ex `componentWillUpdate` instead of render. Why? Well why not. It’s what the specs recommend. If you are calculating sizes "on the fly" in your render method, you are better off calculating them inside the `componentDidMount`, then set states and re-render with your newly calculated measurements.

Comment: Eduardo, you are right about `.refs` not being populated at `componentWillMount()` (I've edited that out), what's different at the time of `componentWillMount()` seems to be rather that at that point the object (passed as `this`) are already the final component object (I've successfully used it to inject later bound methods on components).